# Android Facebook login and to web server

Tags: android, web-services, facebook, authentication

I'm developing an Android app as well as a website (that does have communication with the Android client as well).  I want to use FB login, but the problem I see is this:

Client, Use FB login and then gets an access_token.

How does Client and Web Server communicate just using this access_code since the Web Server needs to know which account the Client is referring to.  I also want to implement FB login on the web site as well.

One method I was thinking was:

Client Login:
1) Use FB login and get access_token.
2) Use access_token to get some User info.
3) Give access_token and User info to web server.
4) Web server also performs the same FB operation with the access_token and retrieves the User info.
5) Validate the User info matches and determine the user account based on that.
6) Establish another access_token between Client and Web Server for this link.

Does this even make it any more valid or perhaps just doing the login and retrieving the user email address as the actual account and tell the Web Server this is the account to use.

Or has someone done this in another way?

Comment: Stephen, did you ever come up with a secure login flow? I'm facing the same issue and your steps are what I was going to try. Wondering if it was successful.

Comment: Brady, did you do something :)

Comment: did you figure this out? either of you: Stephen or @BradyEmerson  I am trying to do the same thing and need to know a good way.

Answer (score 1):

For the communication between your client/server you should use your own client Id.
Don't relay on the access_token facebook gives you because it changed in several scenarios.
Getting the email is also not a full solution because users can decide not to give you their mail.

In general you need to implement Facebook Connect on both sides.

1.Connect to facebook
2.Get permissions from the user (read about permissions here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)
3.Register it as your user and give him an id (you can use facebook uid if you want).

When the user returns to your site/app you need to login him again, get his uid and query your server for the user details.

One thing about the access_token, you need it to query facebook's api. you can get it from facebook every time a user login to your site/mobile using facebook or you can request the user for offline_access permission and then you'll have the same access_token until the user changes their password at facebook etc. (read more about it on the docs).
This method allows you to query facebook api's although the user isn't currently logged in to your site.