# Mobile Facebook & Google login with MVC .Net backend. Android

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, membership-provider

I am struggling with how to create an authorization system for an Android app that is going to have an MVC.Net backend. I want to use a .Net Memebership provider, but also Facebook and Google accounts. Ultimately there will be three ways to login (FB, Google, Forms Auth), each way the backend is a Membership Provider and thus has a user record.

I've read up so much on these topics in relation to Android apps and have watched the Google IO [Android REST client applications](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) video (witch is a must if you want to do things well in Android). But after all this, I'm still no closer to finding out how people create these membership or authorization systems.

So far my idea would be: when a user login's in with Facebook (using SSO) on the app they get a token from Facebook, when they then post things to the website from their mobile they pass this token and their FB userid to the MVC WebAPI service and the server makes a request to FB and checks that the token is valid before actioning any POSTs or PUTs etc.

I'm thinking the same for the Google account, although I've not looked into that at the moment.

Also I want the users to be able to login to the website using the same auth method (FB, Google or normal Forms Auth) as their phone.

I'm really not sure if this is correct architecturally, I haven't seen/can't find any examples of a end to end mobile/web auth system, but need some help on what is generally done.

I've found [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663215/android-facebook-login-and-to-web-server), but it didn't have any votes on the answer so not sure.
I'm sure that this has been done before though!

Comment: Hey Matt, did you come up with a secure login flow? I'm facing the same issue and your steps are what I was going to try. Wondering if it was successful

Comment: Not really successful, I've had to put this project on hold for now to concentrate on paid work!