# Mobile app with Facebook login - how to authenticate users

Tags: facebook, mobile

This is kind of a follow-up to this question: [Android Facebook login and to web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663215/android-facebook-login-and-to-web-server)

Imagine a mobile app is uninstalled and then installed again or a user gets a new phone and installs the app from scratch. Next, the user logs in to FB and the app receives a fresh FB `access_token`.

The next step is to send a "sign in" HTTP request to the backend - but we only have a fresh FB token and nothing else so the backend cannot know right away that it should log in an existing user.

So am I right that the backend has to hit FB API on each & every such "sign in" request from a mobile, as it can never know if it's a brand new user trying to sign up or an existing user trying to sign in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have long-term token that lasts for 60 days
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/